# attachment_fields_to_save first parameter is null

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, attachments, attachment-fields-to-edit

I have the following code in a self-written plugin.
In the function `saveHomepageGalleryCheckbox` the first param (`$post`) is always null. Did I something wrong? The second parameter (`$attachment`) has the correct value.

- Wordpress Version: 5.3.2
- PHP Version: 7.3.15

Code:

```
class MediaView
{
  private $key = 'include_in_homepage_gallery';

  public function __construct()
  {
    add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit', [$this, 'renderHomepageGalleryCheckbox'], 10, 2);
    add_filter('attachment_fields_to_save', [$this, 'saveHomepageGalleryCheckbox'], 10, 2);
  }

  public function renderHomepageGalleryCheckbox(array $fields, WP_Post $post)
  {
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $this->key, true);
    $checked = (boolval($meta) === true) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
    $id = "attachments[{$post->ID}][{$this->key}]";

    $fields[$this->key] = [
      'label' => 'Homepage Gallery',
      'input' => 'html',
      'html' => "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"$id\" id=\"$id\" value=\"1\" {$checked} />"
    ];

    return $fields;
  }

  public function saveHomepageGalleryCheckbox($post, array $attachment) // Here is $post === null
  {
    if (isset($attachment[$this->key])) update_post_meta($post['ID'], $this->key, 1);
    else update_post_meta($post['ID'], $this->key, 0);

    return $post;
  }
}
```

Comment: I notice in your `saveHomepageGalleryCheckbox` filter you never return anything, is there a reason for that? Filters **always** return something. Alos why do you have `null` as the priority? Do you have any other filters operating on `attachment_fields_to_save`?

Comment: I updated my code, but it doesn´t change anything about the `$post` param.

Comment: True, but  they were still issues. Think of it as a kitchen oven repairman telling you the fridge has died, it's not going to fix the oven, but it's still a problem that needs fixing, that's why I left a comment instead of an answer, I'm not sure why your `$post` is null. Note that if another filter has made the same mistake, then this would explain why `$post` is null, as the next filter called would recieve a `null` if the filter did not return anything